# mythconverg_backup.pl crashes with error: Can't use 'defined(@array)'

Tags: mysql, database, mythtv

mythconverg_backup.pl crashes with error "Can't use 'defined(@array)' (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?) at ./mythconverg_backup.pl line 1070."

After new install of xubuntu 16.4 LTS and a successful database restore, I want to backup the database again with the following command:

```
$ ./mythconverg_backup.pl --verbose --directory /home/lukas/mythtv/db_backups
```

The Result is the following error:

```
Can't use 'defined(@array)' (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?) at ./mythconverg_backup.pl line 1070.
```

Can you please give me hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From perldoc ( 5 version 24.0 )**

> Use of **defined** on aggregates (hashes and arrays) is deprecated. It
> used to report whether memory for that aggregate had ever been
> allocated. This behavior may disappear in future versions of Perl. You
> should instead use a simple test for size:
>
> `if (@an_array) { print "has array elements\n" }`

So for you just go the **line 1070** of **mythconverg_backup.pl** and remove the define function from there . For example:

> `if( defined @an_array )` **change it to** `if( @an_array )`